# Remove all the contents from /root ( /~ )directory

Tags: files, software-installation, uninstall

I wanted a software to be installed and its default directory to install was `/root`. But the software could not get installed. Now I want to do it again from scratch. But there are some files in `/root` directory. I am not sure whether they are of the software that I installed or system files. In short I wanted to ask whether the /root directory is empty when we install Ubuntu or has it any system files?

here is the output of the `ls -la` command

```
root@rnt-U410:~# ls -la
total 84
drwx------ 13 root root 4096 Jan  4 23:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 23 19:44 .android
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 19:05 Android
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 23 19:01 .AndroidStudio
-rw-------  1 root root 6955 Jan  3 23:30 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3133 Jan  1 16:53 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3106 Feb 20  2014 .bashrc~
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:28 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:28 .config
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:28 .dbus
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   68 Dec 23 22:24 .gitconfig
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:28 .gvfs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 19:01 .java
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 21:28 .local
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  256 Dec 26 20:47 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  194 Dec 26 20:46 .profile~
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 23 22:21 .repoconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  116 Dec 23 22:24 .repopickle_.gitconfig
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec 25 04:26 .swt
root@rnt-U410:~#
```

Comment: Why would any software want to install in /root??

Comment: Android Studio installs in root directory

Comment: that is poor planning on the developers part then.

Comment: I guess it doesn't install to the root directory (which is actually `/`, the root of the filesystem), nor the `/root` specifically (the home of the root user) but rather to the `$HOME` directory (the home of the user who installs it). You should not install such software as the *root* user but rather as your ordinary user.

Comment: According to the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) no installation is needed for android studio. simply unpack and run it. - As a normal user, not root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp of the files should give you a hint if things were created during your installation.

The `/root` directory is only the home directory of the root user. Nothing important lives there unless you explicitly place it there. Therefore removing everything should be fine. (Maybe you want to keep `.bashrc` and `.profile`.)

Hint: You can compile and install most software as a normal user. No need to use root for that.

Answer (score 0):

The home of root (`/root/`) shouldn't contain anything, and normally its content is coming from programs executed by the user `root` that are saving their preferences/history/whatnot for later re-use.

as suggested by other users, `.bashrc` and `.profile` seems to be something you might want to maintain.

As Linux is a multi-user system, you would normally login with a user with a smaller set of capabilities, and execute root commands through sudo only when needed, to avoid compromising the security of your system.

Unless you're aware that some of these executed programs might contain needed information or preferences, you can delete its content without problems, otherwise just create a copy of what you want before wiping everything (something along the lines of `tar -cvjpf /mnt/backup/backup-root-$(date+%F-%H-%M).tar.bz2 ~/` should be more than enough).